# Dockerfile unable to locate files and directories

Tags: python, docker

I'm using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True
ENV PYTHONPATH /app

WORKDIR /app/services/big_box

RUN pip install "poetry==1.1.8"

COPY ./services/big_box/pyproject.toml \
     ./services/big_box/poetry.lock \
     ./

COPY ./lib ../../lib

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && \
    poetry install --no-dev

COPY ./services/big_box/src ./src

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 'src.app:create_app()'
```

My directory structure is like:
[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZv13.png)

To build the docker image I run the following command from inside backend-python:

```
docker build -t big_box ./services/big_box
```

But I get the following errors:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdDup.png)

I've checked the locations of all directories multiple times but do not know why I'm getting this error. I'm using Mac, VS code, Python, Poetry and Docker.

Comment: Does it just print out the string `Error`?  Or can you [edit] the question to include the text of the error directly in the question (not an image, not behind a link)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the docker build context.

Since you do not specify any different context, docker runs with the default:
The directory holding your dockerfile is the build context. Everything in the context will be zipped and sent to the docker daemon which tries to build the image.
If you try to reference files outside of that context the instruction is bound to fail, and that is what you perceive.

So what you need to do is to specify the current directory as root context, but then you need to tell docker that the Dockerfile is not in the root directory:

```
docker build -t big_box -f /services/big_box/Dockerfile .
```

see https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/understanding-the-docker-build-context-why-you-should-use-dockerignore/